# Is there any way to know how many times my answer was viewed?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

Is there any way to know how many times my answer was viewed?

Let a question have 4 answers.

Now, I want to know how many times the individual answers were viewed. For example:

- question -> viewed 29 times
- answer 1 -> viewed 12 times
- answer 2 -> viewed 15 times
- answer 3 -> viewed 4 times
- answer 4 -> viewed 1 time

Comment: No, but they're working on something similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here

Comment: Can one look at 'an' answer and not at the others?

Comment: Sure! Webcam + eye-tracking software. Now if we can only gain access to everyone's webcam.

Comment: @Jongware: Yes, by using the revision pages. [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54713103/revisions) and [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66950971/revisions). (The ones with only one revision have hidden URLs.). It is not very practical, but it is doable.

Answer (score 6):

No, only the view counts of questions are recorded. The system has no way to tell whether an answer has been viewed.

Answer (score 5):

How would you record the views of an answer?

The question and all its answers are presented on a single page to the viewer (Except if there are large numbers of long answers).  How could the server know, and therefore record, if the viewer scrolled down to look at one question only?

If you can answer that, you would make your fortune.  The purveyors of trackers would beat a path to your door.

Comment: even if I'm not for the feature (waste of dev time IMO), you could at least track how many views since answer A was added. Wouldn't be perfect mind you, but it would be a start

Comment: You could check for viewing time. However not perfect, you can record the time an answer is shown on the screen, if those match with a certain bit of activity (ergo scrolling, clicking) you could say someone has viewed the answer.